# Splitting sequence of letters, whilst retaining original sequence position

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to split the following sequence of letters into distinct chunks

SCDKSFNRGECSCDKSFNRGECSCDKSFNRGEC

I have used the following code provided from a previous user to achieve what I initially wanted, which was to split the sequence after every C.

```
library(dplyr)

TestSequence <- "SCDKSFNRGECSCDKSFNRGECSCDKSFNRGEC"

Test <- strsplit(TestSequence, "(?<=[C])", perl = TRUE) %>% unlist 

df <- data.frame(Fragment = Test) %>%
  mutate("position" = cumsum(nchar(Test)))
```

This allowed me to split the sequence after every C and retain it's position in the sequence, for example C at position 2, 11 etc.

Now I need to split the same sequence at different locations, which I can do using the following to split after P,A,G or S:

```
Test2 <- strsplit(TestSequence, "(?<=[P,A,G,S])", perl = TRUE) %>% unlist
```

This is fine if I want it to split after a given character, but if I try to split it before a character for example D, I cannot seem to retain the D in the fragment.  I can only have it retained if it is split after the D.

I have tried every combination of look behind or look ahead I can think of, the following cuts before and after every D which isn't that useful.

```
Test3 <- strsplit(TestSequence, "(?=[D])", perl = TRUE) %>% unlist
```

Also is there a way to retain the exact position of every C in the original sequence?

So if I were to split the test sequence after the initial K, I'd have a fragment that was SCDK, could I have a separate column that tells me where the C was in the original sequence. Just as a second example, the next fragment would be SFNRGECSCDK and in that separate column it would say the C was originally in position 11.

Comment: In this case, you can use `strsplit(TestSequence, "\\B(?=D)", perl = TRUE)`

Comment: Replace D with a newline and D and then split on newline: `strsplit(gsub("D", "\nD", TestSequence), "\n")[[1]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero-length matches that result from the use of lookahead only patterns used in `strsplit` are not handled properly.

In this case, you need to "anchor" the matches on the left, too. Either use a non-word boundary, or a lookbehind that disallows the match at the start of string:

```r
TestSequence <- "SCDKSFNRGECSCDKSFNRGECSCDKSFNRGEC"
strsplit(TestSequence, "\\B(?=D)", perl = TRUE)
# => [[1]]
# => [1] "SC"          "DKSFNRGECSC" "DKSFNRGECSC" "DKSFNRGEC"  
 
strsplit(TestSequence, "(?<!^)(?=D)", perl = TRUE)
# => [[1]]
# => [1] "SC"          "DKSFNRGECSC" "DKSFNRGECSC" "DKSFNRGEC"
```

See the [online R demo](https://ideone.com/j22CBi).

The `\B(?=D)` pattern matches a location that is immediately preceded with a word char and is immediately followed with `D`.

The `(?<!^)(?=D)` pattern matches a location that is not immediately preceded with a start of string location (i.e. not at the start of string) and is immediately followed with `D`.

Also, note that `[P,A,G,S]` matches `P`, `A`, `G`, `S` *and a comma*. You should use `[PAGS]` to match one of the letters.

Comment: Thanks again Wiktor, that's odd about the  `[P, A, G, S]`, that doesn't appear to be any different to `[PAGS]` 
They seem to produce the same result.

Comment: @AJSmith993 Cf. [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/KZF5D3/1) and [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/KZF5D3/2).